# How to decode javascript elements from an array

Tags: javascript, encoding, decode, deobfuscation

I try to work with javascript from Chrome extension, and have some problems.

Big parts of code including in encode array

```
var _0x6790 = ["\x44\x4F\x4D\x53\x75\x62\x74\x72\x65\x65\x4D\x6F\x64\x69\x66\x69\x65\x64", "\x67\x65\x74", "\x3A\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65", "\x69\x73", "\x24\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x79\x46\x6F\x72\x4C\x6F\x6F\x74\x42\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E", "\x65\x6E\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64", "\x61\x75\x74\x6F\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x69\x6E\x67", "\x73\x65\x74\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x73", "\x6D\x61\x67\x69\x63", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x5F\x62\x69\x64\x49\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x6C\x44\x65\x6C\x61\x79", "\x61\x75\x74\x6F\x62\x69\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67", "\x23\x67\x6F\x6C\x64\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x72", "\x73\x65\x74\x42\x69\x64", "\x6F\x6E", "\x5F\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6E\x63\x65"];
```

and is used like this:

```
$(document)[_0x6790[14]](_0x6790[0], function() {
```

How can I decode the values in the array?

Answer (score -1):

this is a [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ItL8M2TD3B6CBmeZcQaz?p=preview) that can help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>    
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script>
          function hex2a(hex) {
        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=str;
         }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1><u>Hex Decoder</u></h1><br>
        <h3><u>Hex code</u></h3>
        <textarea id="hexcode" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="hex2a(document.getElementById('hexcode').value)">decode</button><br>
        <h3><u>Result</u></h3>
        <textarea id="result" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        </body>    
    </html>
```